# ChannelFlow producer scope is not triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have issue with the following code:

```
suspend fun getData(): Flow<Resource<User>> {
    println("#getData called")
    return channelFlow {
        println("#getData producer scope started")

        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val cachedData = sharedPreferencesUtils.getData()
            println("#getData send cached data")
            send(cachedData)
        }

        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = handleAPI<EducationResponse> { apiService.getData() }
            println("#getData send remote data")
            send(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is working most times and send data from local and remote, but sometimes the producer scope not triggered (it print "#getData called" only)

Please advice!

UPDATE:

and the Flow collected:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(AppExceptionHandler.exceptionHandler) {
            prescriptionsRepository
                    .getData()
                    .collect {
                        educationWithSponsorsLiveData.postValue(it)
                    }

        }
```

Comment: You will need to include the places where `getData()` is used, Flows are cold and only do something if they are collected.

Comment: @Kiskae 
The flow is collected from all places it's called from (actually I calling it from the viewModel), please check the above code that collected the channel.

Note: it's not always happening, and I am not able to reproduce the case in a known scenario, it's suddenly appeared!

Comment: You shouldn't use `suspend`, only `fun getData(): Flow<Resource<User>> { ... }`. Maybe the `suspend` keyword conflicts with the `Flow` declaration.